# icCube XMLA requests in SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: ssl, https, iccube

SSL is enabled in iccube.xml using a self-signed certificate. As describe in the icCube documentation, 8443 is assigned to the sslPortNumber variable, the certificate location is assigned to sslKeyStorePath and the right password is specified for sslKeyStorePassword. The web administration application and gvi requests work fine when using 8443 as the port in the URL.

Unfortunately, sending XMLA requests in SSL using the same port (8443) does not work. What's wrong with the configuration file? Is there another section to fill out in the configuration file that is specific to XMLA? Is there a special way to build the calling URL?

Thank you

Comment: Anything in the logs? Does your XMLA client (which one by the way?) handle properly SSL connections?